# Calculating st_simplify tolerance for OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, postgis

I want to display a vector layer in OpenLayers. Users can scale the map before they load the vector layer and I'd like to simplify the geometry with st_simplify before sending it to the client.

Does anyone have a simple formula I can use to calculate an appropriate st_simplify tolerance based on the map's properties (e.g. zoom, scale or extent?)?

- https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Simplify.html
- http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html

(I don't think this is relevant but have a PHP middle layer and am passing the layer as KML)

I've searched around and maybe I'm looking the wrong way because I can't believe I'm the first one with this question!

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution to this?  I find that the simplification tolerance can be ideal for a particular zoom scale, but when zooming in/out, the simplified geometry becomes completely innappropriate.